# How do I set a custom password with Cloud-init on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, cloud-init, ubuntu-20.04

Recently I've gotten Cloud-Init to work by mounting my config in an image. This is all fine, it works. If I break the config, it tells me. What it doesn't tell me is why I'm not allowed to log on.

What I've tried is creating my own password using `echo possible | mkpasswd -m sha-512 -s` and by copying the example found on the quickstart page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/AutomatedServerInstalls/QuickStart

Neither work. I've tried setting a custom username too. Doesn't change anything. The default `ubuntu:ubuntu` is also unavailable. Neither is ubuntu and blank.

What I'm using:

https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/AutomatedServerInstalls/QuickStart

```
# echo possible | mkpasswd -m sha-512 -s                                    
$6$nqZiIASVBA.iF$9nubU0ImWVrv4XhtEq9XhSh9UYNFQ7yC9Lf7A.uheSlJ3cgI5d9ltkUwRq.X8lAwoQuLAMem6v.gJNGYwk5XA0
```

The following config with it's supplied password, or the above;

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntu-server
    password: "$6$exDY1mhS4KUYCE/2$zmn9ToZwTKLhCw.b4/b.ZRTIZM30JZ4QrOQ2aOXJ8yk96xpcCof0kxKwuX1kqLG/ygbJ1f8wxED22bTL4F46P0"
    username: ubuntu
```

I've also tried setting up a users block like this:

https://gist.github.com/leogallego/a614c61457ed22cb1d960b32de4a1b01#file-ubuntu-cloud-virtualbox-sh-L46-L56

What I'm asking for:

- A better documentation of what type of hash is expected.
- A working user-data config

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've finally found a working config that creates a usable account;

```
users:
  - default
  - name: kim
    passwd: "$6$kW4vfBM9kGgq4hr$TFtHW7.3jOECR9UCBuw9NrdSMJETzSVoNQGcVv2y.RqRUzWDEtYhYRkGvIpB6ml1fh/fZEVIgKbSXI9L1B6xF."
    shell: /bin/bash
    lock-passwd: false
    ssh_pwauth: True
    chpasswd: { expire: False }
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    groups: users, admin
    ssh_authorized_keys:
     - ssh-rsa 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 miesl@mies-pc

autoinstall:
    version: 1
    identity:
        hostname: yamanouchi-node-1
        username: ubuntu
        password: "$6$exDY1mhS4KUYCE/2$zmn9ToZwTKLhCw.b4/b.ZRTIZM30JZ4QrOQ2aOXJ8yk96xpcCof0kxKwuX1kqLG/ygbJ1f8wxED22bTL4F46P0"
    refresh-installer:
        update: yes
```

It creates a user with name `kim` and password `possible`. I'm not entirely sure whether refresh-installer is required (I don't think so). It's insanely insecure with password ssh and no password root, but hey. You can configure that yourself.

The `ubuntu` account remains unusable. I'm at a loss as to why.

Comment: Thanks! For the record, this `users` section also works if put under `autoinstall/user-data`.

Comment: in 20.04 the user-data or users: does not work at all for me, any idea?

Comment: It looks like for all accounts the `lock_passwd` setting defaults to `true`. If you want to log in with the `ubuntu` user, you have to define `lock_passwd: false`. Also note: `lock-passwd` has changed to `lock_passwd`in current versions of cloud-init. See [Users and Group Documentation](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#users-and-groups)

Answer (score 5):

If you add any users via cloud-init, the default `ubuntu` user is not created at all. You will note that the `/home/ubuntu/` directory is absent.

To create my cloud-init that allows SSH authentication, and sets a password so that I can use `sudo`, I have successfully used these steps:

Create a password hash with `mkpasswd`:

```
$ mkpasswd -m sha-512
Password:  <enter your password here>
$6$nq4v1BtHB8bg$Oc2TouXN1KZu7F406ELRUATiwXwyhC4YhkeSRD2z/I.a8tTnOokDeXt3K4mY8tHgW6n0l/S8EU0O7wIzo.7iw1
```

Then, I use this section in my cloud-init:

```
users:
  - name: brandon
    groups: [ sudo ]
    shell: /bin/bash
    lock_passwd: false
    passwd: "$6$nq4v1BtHB8bg$Oc2TouXN1KZu7F406ELRUATiwXwyhC4YhkeSRD2z/I.a8tTnOokDeXt3K4mY8tHgW6n0l/S8EU0O7wIzo.7iw1"
    ssh-authorized-keys:
    - ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1zzzBBBGGGg3BZFFzTexMPpOZJbSa6OlzycjkPhsh4Qg2tSWZyXZ my-key-name
```

I prefer to use the `groups: [ sudo ]` syntax to grant access to sudo via a group, which is personal preference over the usage of the `sudo` directive.

Answer (score 4):

I do not have enough rep to post a comment, but as stated [here](https://github.com/vmware/photon/issues/659#issuecomment-769450194)  and I can confirmed with my tests, to set password for existing user you have to use `hashed_passwd`, not simply `passwd`

Example:

```
#cloud-config
users:
  - name: root
    lock_passwd: false
    hashed_passwd: <output from mkpasswd --method=SHA-512 --rounds=4096>
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ssh-rsa <key>
```

Answer (score 2):

if your image is：focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.img

```
rm -f vm_0001-focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.qcow2
qemu-img create -f qcow2 -F qcow2 -b focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.img  vm_0001-focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.qcow2 20G
qemu-img info vm_0001-focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.qcow2
VM_NAME="ubuntu-20-cloud-image"
USERNAME="programster"
PASSWORD="thisok"
echo "#cloud-config
system_info:
  default_user:
    name: $USERNAME
    home: /home/$USERNAME

password: $PASSWORD
chpasswd: { expire: False }
hostname: $VM_NAME

# configure sshd to allow users logging in using password 
# rather than just keys
ssh_pwauth: True
" | sudo tee user-data
cloud-localds ./cidata.iso user-data
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2048 -smp 4 -hda ./vm_0001-focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.qcow2 \
      -cdrom ./cidata.iso -device e1000,netdev=net0 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22 -nographic
```

another example:

```
rm -f vm_0001-focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.qcow2
qemu-img create -f qcow2 -F qcow2 -b focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.img  vm_0001-focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.qcow2 20G
qemu-img info vm_0001-focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.qcow2
cat >user-data <<'EOF'
#cloud-config
users:
  - default
  - name: jamlee
    homedir: /home/jamlee
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    groups: users, admin
    lock_passwd: false
    shell: /bin/bash
    passwd: $6$yO/Yf/zQbbIXlaHN$cA/i6a6.Cp7cnHl9HEhSPyVLtsitWs3oe/2NARVCKAn54LU2kT92/vqzpeSP3N87SGFkSHGBe7uQxshZXTbL./
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ssh-rsa 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 root@DESKTOP-SBBNAKK
system_info:
    default_user:
      name: ubuntu
      home: /home/ubuntu
password: ubuntu
chpasswd:
    expire: false
hostname: vm-001
ssh_pwauth: yes
EOF
cloud-localds ./cidata.iso user-data
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2048 -smp 4 -hda ./vm_0001-focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.qcow2 \
      -cdrom ./cidata.iso -device e1000,netdev=net0 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22 -nographic
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the very same issue. By using the shell during the installation process, I see that no users are created, hence we cannot log in after the reboot. I don't know why, either a bug in subiquity or a lack of documentation about how to use it properly. Neverteless, I was able to create an user using this trick in my autoinstall file:

```
  late-commands:
    - useradd -m -R /target -u 1001 ubuntu
    - echo "ubuntu:ubuntu" | chroot /target /usr/sbin/chpasswd
    - usermod -R /target -aG sudo ubuntu
```

Comment: Seeing your answer got me searching again and since posting this, a ton of people have complained about the cloud-init implementation. I have however found another config of someone doing something similar (20.04 in Vbox) and their users section includes some options I hadn't seen before. Adding a shell and setting lock-passwd to false appears to fix the issue. What a ride this has been.

Comment: @MiesvanderLippe Would you happen to have a link to the Vbox config page you refer to? I saw your other answer - did you ever find a way to 'fix' the `ubuntu` account?

Comment: I use this with VirtualBox;
https://superuser.com/questions/827977/use-cloud-init-with-virtualbox
But I have scripted it so it mounts automatically using VboxManage commands.

Unsure about ubuntu account. Gave up on this BS after nobody answered & just set up 4 VM's myself. I'm doing the rest of the management using Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

For ubuntu 20.04, I am finding that I cannot login to the console without /etc/securetty. I'm answering with this because it's not clear if you're trying to access your account through the console.

```
runcmd:
    - cp /usr/share/doc/util-linux/examples/securetty /etc/securetty
```

I find if I install /etc/securetty as a runcmd, that I can then log in with these cloud-config users on the system console. Otherwise, authentication will fail.

I make no claims about the security ramifications of deciding to use this example.